# Opciones disponibles para un parámetro en ruta Laravel

Tags: laravel, rutas

¿Se pueden añadir una *constraint* para que un parámetro de una ruta Laravel tenga que estar entre una serie de opciones?

Por ejemplo, en la documentación:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

obliga a que `{name}` siga la expresión regular:

```
Route::get('/user/{name}', function ($name) {
    //
})->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

¿Puede forzarse que `{name}` sea `'gris', 'azul', 'ambar, 'verde' o 'amarillo'`, por poner un ejemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la sintaxis para un "enum" sería `where('opcion','option1|opcion2|...')`

```
Route::get('/{option}', function (string $option) {
    return response()->json([
         'usted seleccionó un color válido!' => $option
    ]);
})->where('option', 'rojo|verde|amarillo');

Route::get('/{option?}', function (string $option) {
    return response()->json([
      'seleccione un color válido. Usted puso la opción' => $option
    ]);
});
```